# Kotlin dataclass function is getting called during serialization

Tags: kotlin, serialization, data-class

I have a couple of data classes in a kotlin project:

```
data class Animation(
    val title: String,
    val userId: Int,
    val height: Int,
    val width: Int,
    val speed: Int,
    val frames: List<Frame>,
    val id: Int? = null
) {
    fun toJson(): String {
        return ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this)
    }

    fun getMeta(): AnimationMeta {
        return AnimationMeta(this.id, this.title)
    }
}

data class AnimationMeta(val id: Int? = null, val title: String)
```

And I have an API endpoint for getting a particular animation by id:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
fun getAnimation(@PathVariable("id") id: Int): Animation {
    return animationService.getAnimation(id) ?: throw ResponseStatusException(NOT_FOUND)
}
```

The business logic behind getAnimation just queries the database, maps the row to the Animation data class, and returns it as is. Nothing special in between.

When I actually call this endpoint, my serialized response includes the call to the getMeta method for some reason:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/rest/animations/35

{
  "title": "Test",
  "userId": 0,
  "height": 0,
  "width": 0,
  "speed": 0,
  "frames": [],
  "id": 35,
  "meta": {
    "id": 35,
    "title": "Test"
  }
}
```

How is the function getting called? I'm sure this is some detail that I'm not seeing in the kotlin docs, but I can't quite figure it out.

## Update

After digging a bit I found that I can use the @JsonIgnore annotation to suppress the function call during serilaization:

```
    @JsonIgnore
    fun getMeta(): AnimationMeta {
        return AnimationMeta(this.id, this.title)
    }
```

But I'm leaving the question up because I don't know *why* I need to use this. I'm used to using it for ignoring properties, but I still don't get why the function call is happening in the first place. It's not like the `toJson` function is getting called, so why is `getMeta` getting called?

Comment: I don't know how the internal serialization of retrofit work but I think because you use the prefix get retrofit treat it as a backing field for a property named meta. So when retrofit tries to create the Animation class, it create the meta property using the backing field that you provided (the getMeta method).

So, using the @JsonIgnore annotation will prevent the deserializer to use the backing field.

Comment: Using “get” at the start of a argumentless function name is an anti pattern in Kotlin because it looks like a Java getter, but Kotlin uses properties instead. In bytecode, all your properties are converted to Java getters, and these are what Retrofit calls to convert your class, so your oddly named function is included among them.

Comment: To get more specific data, you could add to `getAnimation` a bit of code to prints/logs the current stacktrace. The stacktrace may lead to the root cause.

Comment: @JolanDAUMAS and tenfour04 yeah you're right. I forgot about that detail in kotlin. I ended up changing the method name to remove the get to resolve the issue. Jolan, I see that you answered the question but it's showing as deleted. It says it was deleted by the author but that's def not true b/c I'm just seeing all of the comments. I voted to have it undeleted and if it does I'll throw you the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the internal serialization of retrofit work but I think because you use the prefix `get` retrofit treat it as a backing field for a property named `meta`. So when retrofit tries to create the Animation class, it create the `meta` property using the backing field that you provided (the `getMeta` method).

So, using the `@JsonIgnore` annotation will prevent the deserializer to use the backing field.